# Can a sequence contain a single element and if yes, does it make literal sense?

Tags: sequences-and-series

When we talk about sequence in general(not necessarily in math), we think of a certain number of things but in a specific order. When only 1 element is present, does the 'order' part make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "make sense"? A sequence of only 1 term does exist and it is usually called a stationary sequence.

Comment: I'm having trouble explaining it my college who says "calling a single element in the open world as a sequence does not make sense because when there are more than 1 elements in a sequence, one can always infer 'this comes after this' which is not possible when only a single element is present." He says a single element is just that - a single element - and not a sequence because of this reason.

Comment: Well I think it is nearly the same as drawing a circle of radius $0$. Does have sense? It is just a point, but it is also a circle ! And as Martund said about the represantation, there is no condition that assures that $a_i\ne a_j$, we can have $a_1=a_2=a_3=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think people are talking at cross-purposes here. suren27, when you say only one element is present, do you mean the sequence is just $(a)$ for some $a$? Or do you mean $(a,a,a,\ldots)$? I assume the former, but FareedAbiFarraj (in the comments) and Martund (in an answer) seem to assume the latter.

The [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) allows a sequence to be finite or infinite, and if you agree with this, then sure, $(a)$ is a sequence. And so is $(a,a,a,\ldots)$.